# Creating a tar.gz file with files that starts with C, in subdirectories

Tags: shell, tar, glob

I have 1280 folders (Their names are 1, 2, 3, ..., 1280). Inside each folder I have several .txt files. However, I would like to create a single tar.gz file just for the .txt files that start with the letter "C".

Is it possible to do it? Any help would be great! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and tar:

```
tar -cvzf your.tar.gz */C*.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Cyrus! I really appreciate it